# Scala / SBT - dependency not resolved on PaaS (cloudControl & heroku)

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt, cloudcontrol, stormpath

I have a simple `Scala` application built using [spray.io](http://spray.io/). I am using `Scala 2.11.2` and `SBT 0.13.0`. All of my dependencies are listed here:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka"  %% "akka-actor"          % "2.3.6",
  "com.typesafe.akka"  %% "akka-slf4j"          % "2.3.6",
  "io.spray"            % "spray-can_2.11"      % "1.3.2",
  "io.spray"            % "spray-routing_2.11"  % "1.3.2",
  "io.spray"            % "spray-json_2.11"     % "1.3.1"
)

libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.7.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.stormpath.sdk" % "stormpath-sdk-api" % "1.0.RC4.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.stormpath.sdk" % "stormpath-sdk-httpclient" % "1.0.RC4.2"
```

While building and running it locally everything is fine but when i try to push / deploy it to `PaaS` platforms like [cloudControl](http://cloudcontrol.com) or [heroku](http://heroku.com) i am getting below dependency issue:

```
   [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;${httpclient.version} ...
   [warn]   module not found: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;${httpclient.version}
   [warn] ==== local: tried
   [warn]   /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/.sbt_home/.ivy2/local/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/${httpclient.version}/ivys/ivy.xml
   [warn] ==== public: tried
   [warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/${httpclient.version}/httpclient-${httpclient.version}.pom
   [warn] ==== spray repo: tried
   [warn]   http://repo.spray.io/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/${httpclient.version}/httpclient-${httpclient.version}.pom
   [warn] ==== spray nightlies: tried
   [warn]   http://nightlies.spray.io/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/${httpclient.version}/httpclient-${httpclient.version}.pom
   [warn] ==== public: tried
   [warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/${httpclient.version}/httpclient-${httpclient.version}.pom
```

...

```
   [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   [warn]   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
   [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   [warn]   :: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;${httpclient.version}: not found
   [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   [warn]   ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
   [warn]   :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
   [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   [warn]   :: com.stormpath.sdk#stormpath-sdk-api;1.0.RC4.2!stormpath-sdk-api.jar
   [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;${httpclient.version}: not found
```

...

```
   [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;${httpclient.version}: not found
   [error] download failed: com.stormpath.sdk#stormpath-sdk-api;1.0.RC4.2!stormpath-sdk-api.jar
   [error] Total time: 59 s, completed May 4, 2015 1:05:37 PM
```

Inspecting my dependencies using [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) shows me that not resolved `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient` is a nested dependency of `com.stormpath.sdk:stormpath-sdk-httpclient:1.0.RC4.2`.

For some reason variable `${httpclient.version}` is not resolved during built - but that is all I can figure it out here. Please help!!!

Comment: seems like you forgot an `s` before a string. look at your dependencies, and search for a: `"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "${httpclient.version}"` and change it to: `s"${httpclient.version}"`

Comment: @giladhoch but `httpclient` is a nested dependency of `com.stormpath.sdk:stormpath-sdk-httpclient:1.0.RC4.2` - i do not specify it explicitly.

Comment: yes, sorry, I saw it too late. @pedrofurla solution should work for you. also, you can use `dependencyOverrides` key instead of excluding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what is going on. But excluding the transitive dependency and adding it to SBT explicitily seems to fix the problem, at least the unresolved dependency problem:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.stormpath.sdk" % "stormpath-sdk-httpclient" % "1.0.RC4.2" exclude("org.apache.httpcomponents","httpclient")

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.2.2"
```

But keep in mind that we don't really know which version of apache's httpclient `stormpath-sdk-httpclient` used in its compilation, so you might run into runtime classpath/linking related exceptions. If that happens I recommend asking the developers of `stormpath-sdk-httpclient`.

#### EDIT:

you can see the version they used at:
https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/blob/master/pom.xml#L98

Comment: This is the correct answer - I have no idea why you have to exclude a transitive dependency only to add it back in again.  Must be an `sbt` issue.

Comment: @Hazlewood it's not a "sbt issue". It seems that the artifact in question was published with malformed pom.xml, not specifying the version correctly. (To be more accurate, it was specified in a parent pom, but the actual published pom did not refrenced it)

Comment: True. I did't bother mentioning that because it'd not help the solution.